# Link View Controllers to Mirror

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, facebook, segue

My application has a Facebook Login screen, which after login shows a **profile picture, username, email, and logout button**.

I am trying to figure out how to link the current users profile picture with a **UIView** or **UIImageView** (which ever is more applicable, given I used a UIView called **FBProfilePictureView**) in the main VC called **HomeViewController**. Here is the code I have for the **LoginViewController** that has the FB information asked for and returned. I also have it segue to the **HomeViewController** once the user info has been entered.

**LoginViewController.h:**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>
#import <FacebookSDK/FacebookSDK.h>

@interface LoginViewController : UIViewController <FBLoginViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBLoginView *loginButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblLoginStatus;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblUsername;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *lblEmail;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet FBProfilePictureView *profilePicture;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *loginwallpaper;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *loggedinwallpaper;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *FBlogin;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *FBlogout;

@end
```

and here is the **LoginViewController.m**

```
#import "LoginViewController.h"

@interface LoginViewController ()

- (void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide;

@end

@implementation LoginViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    self.loginButton.readPermissions = @[@"public_profile", @"email"];
    self.loginButton.layer.cornerRadius = 0;
    [self.loginButton.layer setBorderWidth:0.0f];

    self.loginButton.delegate = self;


    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}

-(void)toggleHiddenState:(BOOL)shouldHide{
    self.lblUsername.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.lblEmail.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.profilePicture.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.loggedinwallpaper.hidden = shouldHide;
    self.FBlogout.hidden = shouldHide;
}

-(void)toggleUnhiddenState:(BOOL)shouldShow{
    self.loggedinwallpaper.hidden = NO;
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedInUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    [self toggleHiddenState:NO];
    [self toggleUnhiddenState:YES];
}

-(void)loginViewShowingLoggedOutUser:(FBLoginView *)loginView{
    self.lblLoginStatus.text = @"";

    [self toggleHiddenState:YES];
}

-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    self.profilePicture.profileID = user.objectID;
    self.lblUsername.text = user.name;
    self.lblEmail.text = [user objectForKey:@"email"];

    UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main" bundle:nil];
    UITabBarController *tabcontroller = (UITabBarController *)[storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"HomeViewController"];
    [self presentViewController:tabcontroller animated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)loginView:(FBLoginView *)loginView handleError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

All of the other questions posted on here have not really helped me - they have been too vague.

If someone could just show me how to connect this profile picture to a UIImageView or UIView in the **HomeViewController** that would be awesome! I know this is easy and I'm just frustrated that this is giving me such an problem

(I know that I need to use the prepareForSeuge method I am just not sure on the syntax of how to accomplish this.)

Answer (score 0):

It will help you. Go to HomeViewController.xib and here put UIView by dragging it.

Now, select that view and on the right side of XCode click on third tab that is Identity Inspector. Here set the class name as  `FBProfilePictureView` then try.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to diplay image in FBProfilePictureView then

Xib/StoryBoard -> Identity Inspector -> class name -> FBProfilePictureView

```
-(void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user{
    NSLog(@"%@", user);
    self.profilePicture.profileID = user.id;
}
```

If you want to display in imageview

```
queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH,0);

 dispatch_async( queue, ^{


            // Load UImage from URL
            NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://graph.facebook.com/%@/picture?width=200&height=200", user.id]];

            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

            // Then to set the image it must be done on the main thread
            dispatch_sync( dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                yourImageView.image =  image
                image = nil;
            });

        });
```